# Checking whether any row combinations of a tall rectangular matrix are linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a tall $n_r \times n_c$ matrix  $M$ (where $n_r > n_c$). I want to ensure that any $n_c$ rows of $M$ are linearly independent, i.e., any square $n_c \times n_c$ sub-matrix $S$ formed by taking $n_c$ rows of $M$ is nonsingular.

Now I just iterate through all row combinations and test the determinants for a fixed $M,n_r,n_c$. But there are $\binom{n_r}{n_c}$ combinations, which quickly become infeasible to iterate as $n_c$ and $n_r$ grow. Are there better tests?

Comment: It seems to be an NP-complete problem but I cannot find an easy statement of that. You may want to read https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/user/dwoodruf/www/biwx.pdf. Also the following MSE question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1076948/efficient-way-of-checking-linear-independence

Comment: Just curious, can you provide a little more info about why you want to ensure that *any* combination of $n_c$ rows are linearly independent (versus just *some* combination)?

Comment: @blargoner Hi, it's for an error correction algorithm I am working on. Before I was thinking of generating a random matrix. Now I may simply use $[1^{r_i},2^{r_i}...n_c^{r_i}]$.

Comment: @Jean-ArmandMoroni Thanks, It seems it's related a term called spark and sadly is NP-Hard to compute.

Comment: @somebody4 NP-whatever does not imply that you cannot solve many instances of interest in a few minutes.

Comment: If I understand the question right, what you are trying to do is impossible. Take $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$. If you take the rows $1$ and $3$ the submatrix becomes singular. Do you mean taking subsequent rows?

Comment: @obareey I assume that this is a decision problem.  You produced a matrix for which the output is `False`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I think I would do.

Let $U_1$ be the unitary matrix that gives lower triangular matrix ie

$$
T_1 = MU_1
$$
where $T_1$ looks something like (for example with $n_r = 7$ and $n_c = 4$)

$\pmatrix{*&0&0&0\\ *&*&0&0\\ *&*&*&0\\ *&*&*&*\\ *&*&*&*\\ *&*&*&*\\
*&*&*&*}$

Compute $T_1$. If the main diagonal has no zeros then the first $n_c$ rows are fully checked against each other for linear independence. If there are no zeros in the last column under the diagonal, then all those ($n_r - n_c + 1$) rows are checked for linear independence from the first ($n_c - 1$) rows.

If such zeros are found, the algorithm stops and returns false.

If no zeros, from there take the sub-matrix of the last $n_r - n_c + 1$ rows and repeat the process

Comment: I do however think this somehow does not thoroughly check all combinations, but maybe more thought into exactly what subsets are checked with this could give something of a speedup, because this process does check all combinations of the first $n_c -1$ rows with the rest at least

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach doesn't work. Consider the matrix $M=\pmatrix{1&0&0\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&0&1\\ 1&0&1\\ 0&1&1}$. Its first three rows are already in the in desired triangular form (so $T_1=M$) and the remaining two rows don't have zeros in their last column. The last $(5-3+1)=3$ rows are linearly independent too. Yet, the first, third and fourth (or second, third and fifth) rows are not linearly independent.

Comment: @PeterKošinár The last 3 are independent from the first 2. That is all I said was checked, so your example does show how my method is not exhaustive. It only checked all combinations involving the first 2 rows

Comment: Indeed, that's why I added a small explicit example of a matrix which shows the algorithm presented does not solve the original question in full.